# efficiently parse binary input in R

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe

within R I have two rows of a dataframe 
every number itself is stored in a separate column..

currently I am using

```
unname(which(df[1,]-df[2,]==0))->hte
```

to find spots in which the there are instances in which there are instances of row 1 equal 1 and row 2 equals 1 as well as row 1 equals 0 and row 2 equals 0. Thatakes quite a bit of time for 70k cols

Comment: I assume this is a single column and the column class as character or is it multiple column (based on another question you recently asked)

Comment: @akrun no sorry these are all different columns...so every number 0 1 and so on is in a different column in a df

Comment: You don't need the difference. would this be faster `which(df1[1,]==df1[2,])`

Comment: @akrun both solution suggestion have not taken over 20 min which is kind of long for such a vector (1.8mil values )..just to determine whether it is an instance of 1,1 or 00

Answer (score 2):

You could convert it to matrix by taking the transpose.  It seems to be fast

```
 system.time({ m1 <- t(df1)
              which(m1[,1]==m1[,2])})
 #  user  system elapsed 
 #  0.31    0.00    0.31
```

Or `unlist`

```
 system.time(which(unlist(df1[1,])==unlist(df1[2,])))
 #   user  system elapsed 
 #  1.175   0.002   1.177
```

#### data

```
library(stringi)
write.table(stri_rand_strings(2, 70000, '[0-1]'), file='binary1.txt', 
           row.names=FALSE, quote=FALSE, col.names=FALSE)
df1 <- read.table(pipe("awk '{gsub(/./,\"& \", $1);print $1}' binary1.txt"))
```

Comment: A data frame is a list and it was my suspicion that this could be slowing down the operation.